# Keep Show/Hide Web Part Selection after Page Refresh (SPO)

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, jquery

The Goal is if I choose to HIDE a WebPart, I would like that WebPart to remain HIDDEN until I manually click the SHOW button, regardless if the page is refreshed or not.

This is the script that I'm using, which dynamically shows/hides Web Parts when the btnShow or btnHide are clicked. Any help is appreciated and thanks!

```
<a href="#"><img src="/SiteAssets/elements/images/eye-invisible.png" accesskey="o" type="button" id="hideObj" class="btnHideObj" title="Click here to HIDE the List" style="height:33px; width: 33px;"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="/SiteAssets/elements/images/eye-visible.png" accesskey="o" type="button" id="showObj" class="btnShowObj" title="Click here to SHOW the List" style="height:33px; width: 33px;"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btnHideObj").show()
    $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ1').show();
    $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2').show();

    $(".btnHideObj").click(function(){
        $(".btnHideObj").hide()
        $(".btnShowObj").show()
        $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ1').hide();
        $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2').hide();
    });
    $(".btnShowObj").click(function(){
        $(".btnHideObj").show()
        $(".btnShowObj").hide()
        $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ1').show();
        $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2').show();

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: So if the WebPart is Visible and you reload the page it should remain its (visible) state?

Comment: That's correct. It should only be hidden when I manually click the HIDE button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sessionStorage to store a value that indicates wether to hide or to show webparts, and your code will be :

```
<a href="#"><img src="/SiteAssets/elements/images/eye-invisible.png" accesskey="o" type="button" id="hideObj" class="btnHideObj" title="Click here to HIDE the List" style="height:33px; width: 33px;"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="/SiteAssets/elements/images/eye-visible.png" accesskey="o" type="button" id="showObj" class="btnShowObj" title="Click here to SHOW the List" style="height:33px; width: 33px;"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $(".btnShowObj").show();

        if(sessionStorage.getItem("Show") == "false")
        {
            $(".btnHideObj").hide();
            $(".btnShowObj").show();
            $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ1').hide();
            $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2').hide();
        }

        $(".btnHideObj").click(function(){
            sessionStorage.setItem("Show", "false");
            $(".btnHideObj").hide();
            $(".btnShowObj").show();

            $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ1').hide();
            $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2').hide();
        });
        $(".btnShowObj").click(function(){
            sessionStorage.setItem("Show", "true");

            $(".btnHideObj").show();
            $(".btnShowObj").hide();
            $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ1').show();
            $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2').show();

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for long jQuery scripts,

HTML5 has the `hidden` attribute for DOM elements:

**Hide:**

```
document.getElementById('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2').setAttribute('hidden','');
```

**Show:**

```
document.getElementById('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2').removeAttribute('hidden');
```